# Applet not running on web - RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception, applet, runtime

I managed to deploy my applet using this tutorial

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html

The applet runs okay inside netbeans, but when I launch from browser it gives me an exception saying this:

RuntimeException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I don't know what do? Can someone help me? the console at java is also clear.. where are the logs?

Found a way to show the console, here is the error:

http://s7.postimg.org/5xlus3auz/error.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is the console error http://s7.postimg.org/5xlus3auz/error.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You are trying to access an image file in a folder, which can not be accessed by the Applet. So put the image file in relative path to your codebase.
When running Applet in NetBeans, it have full permissions. But when running in browser, JVM runs Applet in secure environment. If still want to access file from not permitted location, digitally sign the Applet. See screen shot:

Comment: So what can I do ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: You can include image file in JAR itself and access the file using `applet.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.png")`

Comment: it will work ? I am using now ImageIO.read(new File(fileName)

Comment: No, use `ImageIO.read(applet.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("<file_path>"))`, Where file_path is relative path of the file (image) to codebase

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what do you mean by codebase ? its the bin folder? thanks ;)

Comment: Not only the bin folder, sometimes the JAR may contain other folder's contents also like resources folder. If you have all your content in bin folder, you can use path relative to bin folder.